# Do I need hystrix dependency when I need @Retry and use spring initializr?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hystrix, spring-retry, spring-initializr

I gonna use `@Retry` in my Spring Boot MVC application while storing a data to DB with optimistic locking via `@Version`.

I gonna retry multiple times when OptimisticLockException exception happens. And fall down after 100 times (for my logic it's a trigger to check something wrong happened)

So is it a Circuit Breaker pattern described above? Should I use Hystrix dependency for it when creating a project in Spring initializr? Or can I just add `spring-retry` dependency in gradle/maven and use `@Retry`? 
I confused, please help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Hystrix for retrying a database call when it fails. You can use the declarative retry (e.g. [`@Retryable`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry#declarative-retry) and other annotations) or the [imperative API](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry#features-and-api) from [spring-retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry).

As far as dependencies go, yes - just add spring-retry and, if using the declarative retry, there is an additional [runtime dependency](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry#additional-dependencies) on AOP classes.

(all of the links above point to the same GitHub Spring project)

Comment: thank you, could you please clarify why Hystrix is a special case?

Comment: I don't see Hystrix as a special case here. One reason for me to point you to spring-retry is that Hystrix is in [maintenance mode](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix#hystrix-status). I've successfully used spring-retry to retry DB calls to MySQL that fail due to a deadlock caused by next key locks (a MySQL "thing"). But you probably will also be successful with Hystrix if you decide to go with it. And just to point out something - `@Retry` is from Hystrix, `@Retryable` is from spring-retry.

Comment: I guess I got carried away a bit - `@Retry` is from resilience4j?

Comment: I don't know where `@Retry` I just wanna understand, if Hystrix do the same as usual `@Retry` why it has a special mention in spring initializr?

Comment: If the use case is to retry a database update that fails due to optimistic locking detecting a change in the underlying data, I'd say that it is _not_ the [Circuit Breaker pattern](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html). So, just add spring-retry as a dependency in gradle/maven and use `@Retryable`.